# WebStorm support for Vue.js directives

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, vuejs2, javascript-intellisense

How come I can see some Vue.js intellisense support

[image]

but `v-on:input` is not recognized

[image]

I use WebStorm 2017.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the erros in the editor I used this line `<html xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v-bind="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`.

I am not an expert on both Webstorm/PHPStorm and Vue but maybe they are trying to let you use the shorthand function with `@` for `v-on:` and `:` for `v-bind`.

Personally I like to use the shorthand way of doing it.